# Defining variable for breadcrumb menu?

Tags: javascript, breadcrumbs

I found a breadcrumb navigation generator online. I have included the code. It pulls the information for the current page from the title. I don't want it to pull from the title because that creates too long of a trail. The titles of pages are something like Page Name - Folder Name - My Company. This is for work so I can't change the format of the titles.

I tried defining a variable on each page called pageName and changing title to pageName in the crumb code but that doesn't seem to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pageName= 'Name';
</script>
```

How would I go about defining the variable so that it works. Or pull just the first portion of the page title before the dash?

```
function breadcrumbs(){
  sURL = new String;
  bits = new Object;
  var x = 0;
  var stop = 0;
  var output = "<div class=breadcrumbs><A HREF=/>Home</A> &nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp; ";

  sURL = location.href;
  sURL = sURL.slice(8,sURL.length);
  chunkStart = sURL.indexOf("/");
  sURL = sURL.slice(chunkStart+1,sURL.length)

while(!stop){
  chunkStart = sURL.indexOf("/");
  if (chunkStart != -1){
    bits[x] = sURL.slice(0,chunkStart)
    sURL = sURL.slice(chunkStart+1,sURL.length);
  }
  else{
    stop = 1;
  }
  x++;
}

for(var i in bits){
  output += "<A HREF=\"";
  for(y=1;y<x-i;y++){
    output += "../";
  }
  output += bits[i] + "/\">" + bits[i] + "</A> &nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp; ";
}
document.write(output + document.title);
    document.write("</div>");
}
```

Comment: Whoever wrote that code is a nincompoop. Whoever heard of creating a String object in JavaScript, much less creating it and then promptly throwing it away by assigning an existing string to the same variable?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
document.write(output + document.title);
```

To:

```
document.write(output + pageName);
```

This assumes that `pageName` is defined on each page this code appears on.

You could improve on this with this code:

```
if (typeof pageName != 'undefined')
{
    document.write(output + pageName);
}
else
{
    document.write(output + document.title);
}
```

This code will use the `pageName` if it exists, otherwise it falls back on the page title.